# Preventing the "click" when stopping SourceDataLine

Tags: java, javasound

I am making a small tool for playing and syncing multiple audio files in Java. I am using `SourceDataLine` to which my code has to submit the audio data for playback. The problem is that whenever I stop such a playback, a small "click" sound is heard which is unacceptable for what I need to use this program for.

I need to use `SourceDataLine` specifically because it gives me the control necessary for the tool to work which is why I can't use `Clip`. Allthough this problem is present there as well.

I also need my tool to be compatible with most `AudioFormat`s Java supports.

Here's a short code that has this problem:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class ClickTest {
    public static final File file = new File("ClickTest.wav");
    public static void main(String[] atgs) throws Throwable{
        AudioInputStream input = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        input.transferTo(output);
        input.close();
        byte[] data = output.toByteArray();//Now we have the file content
        AudioFormat format = input.getFormat();
        System.out.println(format);
        //Example case: PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
        SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format);
        line.open(format);
        System.out.println(line.getBufferSize());
        //Prints 88200 which is 22050 frames (half a second) in my case
        line.start();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()+5000l;
        //I am aware that this blocks but it returns before the end of the 5-second playback.
        line.write(data, 0, (int)(format.getFrameSize()*format.getFrameRate()*5));
        assert(endTime > System.currentTimeMillis());//Assertion succeeds
        LockSupport.parkUntil(endTime);
        line.stop();//We don't really need this call because the line is reaching the end about now.
        line.close();//Prevent resource leak
    }
}
```

The above code is supposed to load a file (about 10 seconds long audio file) and play the first five seconds of it before stopping.

While the documentation for `stop()` does not say anything, the documentation for `flush()` does mention the "click" that can be heard when the 5 second playback ends. To be clear, I know what causes it but I don't know how to prevent it.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this clicking sound at the end of playbacks?

Comment: What Java version are you using, and in what operating system are you running?  Java 11 on Linux 4.19.0 64-bit does not seem to generate a click.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 64 bit with Java 11 (but with compiler compliance level 10). I did not know it could depend on it.

Comment: I can’t seem to reproduce it on Windows 10 64-bit, either.  Do other sound files cause the problem as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected result of the abrupt stop. The signal has suddenly gone from a wave to nothing, and that transition (a "discontinuity") generates energy in a manner similar to an impulse click.

The solution I employ in my audio work is to taper the volume over an number of frames, e.g., 1028 is used for smoothing out such clicks in [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue/blob/master/src/main/java/com/adonax/audiocue/AudioCue.java). The code there handles commands to change volume by spreading out the transition over multiple frames. But it might be hard to read without a lot of context. If you do take a look, the most relevant lines are 110, 896-900 and 1301-1322. Also, that code is used for volume changes in any direction, not just for smoothing from 1 to 0 as needed for your situation.

In your case, the task is as follows:

1. convert the `SourceDataLine` bytes to PCM values
2. over the course of a number of frames (I use 1028 to be on the safe side, but you might find it okay to use a smaller number), multiply the PCM value by a factor that transitions from 1 to 0 over the chosen number of frames
3. convert the PCM values back to bytes

Yes this is a lot of trouble.

Another possibility to explore is to see if you can use a volume [Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/controls.html). Java attempts to provide a "Volume" and a "Master Gain". But neither are guaranteed (I've had more success with the master). Also, the values of these are not consulted on a per-frame basis, but only on a per-buffer basis. Depending upon the size of the buffer being used by your `SourceDataLine`, that will significantly reduce the rate at which you can change the volume without getting "zippering" (tiny clicks due to discontinuities) or other artifacts. On that basis a much larger increment (than 1/1028) would be needed, but that increases the likelihood that there might be a click.

Comment: This is a load of nonsense- then all music players would be criking and scratching- You essentually proposing a long fade out. Thats it!

Comment: 1024 frames at 44100 fps is 0.0232 parts of a second, less than 1/40th of a second. Do you think of that as a long fade out?

Comment: The fact that it's a fade out means I would have to write (or generate) separate pieces of code for every single PCM format that I want to support. The amount of bits per PCM value can vary and it can even be in floating point values or unsigned. Performance-wise, it might not even be fast enough to play. It would mean processing 1028*4 bytes of data on a high level which my program would have to do faster than it is played because it can't know in advance when the user hits the pause button. This solution would cost me a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Yes, as I said, a lot of trouble. Maybe the Controls solution will give a "good enough" softening of the click. It doesn't care about format. If you are a decent coder, there shouldn't be a performance hit with the per frame algo, but I restrict to 16-bit stereo wav, no mp3 or ogg decompression. I've not had a problem, and use it on numerous audio applications that I have built including realtime synthesis. If you find another solution, I'm all ears! Maybe check out the TinySound library (on github) as it also has faders. Also, even 32-frame fades work in a majority of situations.

Comment: The control solution is hindered by the buffer size. It happens to be too big. I either ended up with zippering or had to extend the fade out time to more than a second which is definitely noticeable and is something I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: The problem with the PCM editing solution is that my thread assigned to working at the line tries to call the write method as few times as possible and only ever writes as much as allowed by "available" because it's responsible for other (timing) tasks related to the same line. The line's internal buffer causes flexibility problems. I did try the PCM editing solution and it does not work because the time it takes the internal buffer to reach the fade out is noticeable. (Up to half a second right now) There are other synching problems I didn't mention yet that also hinder this solution.

Comment: A line that calls the audio write should be dedicated to that and not have any other responsibilities. There is no need to manage the frequency of the write method because it makes use of a blocking queue. It will basically spend something 95% of its time (very crude estimate on my part) waiting for the next stage to clear. Thus, it consumes very little cpu. You can probably even set the thread priority to high and as long as it is just dealing with the audio, it will have little impact on the rest of your system.

Comment: The write loop can interact with other threads via a loosely coupled boolean, e.g., "running". There can be code that inspects the local "running" boolean, and when it goes false, initiates the fadeout. I don't know why it is taking half a second for you. If done right (I may not have explained it well enough) it can take well under 1/50th of a second and not create a click of any sort.

Comment: The example I have given above is really just an example that demonstrates the problem I'm dealing with. You have no idea how my actual code looks like. I have to structure it in a way that keeps the line's internal buffers at least half full all the time. The thread responsible for filling it returns from the write method with the internal buffer full, and witnesses the flag indicating that it should fade the audio out. It now generates the fade out and writes it to the line, but it will take half a second for the internal buffer of the line to reach the fade out which is noticeable.

Comment: This problem is only present on some computers which gives me the impression it's not supposed to be solved on Java's high level, but on a native level instead. (Sound cards or other native code) I have inspected the Controls the line gives me both with and without using a Mixer and I haven't found the value I need to change yet.

Comment: You aren't actually using the SDL for output? What then? Are you committed to a library, such as libjdx? I was working on a wrapper for this but decided it was too much trouble as I don't use it. I did make a wrapper once for Android devices. This may be more about a library or framework than Java. I smooth out volume, panning and frequency changes, in real time, in AudioCue (linked in the answer), using a SourceDataLine in its own thread. The Java tutorials only mentions using Controls or taking a DIY approach as I do. Hard to talk about using something else without more info.